# Transfer a file from Local machine to Sharepoint folder using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I would like to process files from my local drive and push to Sharepoint
I have the company sharepoint url and i also have a link to the folder i would like to push my files to
Please help

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

@Ngala Hassan,

There is a python library that offer a quick method to upload file to sharepoint:

- https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html#folders

You may also take a reference of below demo:

```html
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

authcookie = Office365('https://abc.sharepoint.com',
                       username='admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com', password='xxxxxxx').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/t01',
            version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/This Folder')

filepath = r"D:\ztest\test.html"

with open(filepath, 'rb+') as file_input:
    try:
        folder.upload_file(file_input, "test.html")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

BR

Comment: would you mind connecting(samini099@gmail.com) i would like to contract someone to help me a little on this task